# ctags doesn't understand -e option (no exuberant tags option)

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

When I type `ctags -e` it returns an error saying it doesn't know that command line option. I thought it should know about exuberant tags because `etags` works on cli.

Also, I recieve the following error: `ctags: unrecognized option --langdef=arc` and I have the following in my ~/.ctags file:

```
--langdef=arc
--langmap=arc:.arc
--regex-arc=/^\(def ([a-zA-Z1-9_*\/<>-]+)/\1/
--regex-arc=/^\(= ([a-zA-Z1-9_*\/<>-]+)/\1/
--regex-scheme=/^\(xdef ([a-zA-Z1-9_*\/<>-]+)/\1/
```

Comment: The string "unrecognized" doesn't appear anywhere in exuberant-ctags, so I'm curious how you're getting that error.  Are you sure you're actually running `/usr/bin/ctags`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`etags` is short for "Emacs tags", not "exuberant ctags".  It sounds like you have Emacs' `etags` command installed, not exuberant-ctags'.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! many things start making more sense :)

Answer (score 10):

It turns out that my system has basic ctags installed, but *not* exuberant-ctags. so even though some `etags` command existed, exuberant-ctags is still different in some way or another.

`sudo apt-get install ctags` fixed the problem

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

solved the problem for me.
I was running Debian Jessie on an ARM development board, cubietruck.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, Emacs comes with etags and a similar executable file called ctags. In the emacs distribution, etags.exe = ctags.exe  in the bin directory.
You should download Exuberant Ctags from http://ctags.sourceforge.net/
Only exuberant ctags recognize -e option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my error occurred because I had installed emacs with flatpak which came bundled with its own version of ctags, distinct from the one I installed with my linux package manager.

In such case the solution is to either specify the ctags path in the emacs config or use the normal non flatpak version.