# How can I jump to class/method definition in Atom text editor?

Tags: atom-editor

Is there an easy way to do this? On Aptana I used <kbd>Control</kbd>+click and I wish there was a way to do something similar on Atom.

Comment: Atom on it's own doesn't have that feature, you can install some packages that do handle it https://atom.io/packages/navigate

Comment: @iroegbu I tried the package but it doesn't work as expected and that 'double click to go to definition' business is also not warranted because sometimes you simply want to select some code nugget and what it does is jump to a new file without the option of going back (f3 doesn't work).

Comment: I don't use Atom, you might want to check out https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-simple-go-to-definition/11809

Comment: Thanks @iroegbu I'll definitely watch the page to see what pops up.

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-simple-go-to-definition

Comment: autocomplete-python-jedi  is the only one that uses ctrl-click .

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I had the same issue and [atom-goto-definition](https://github.com/faceair/atom-goto-definition) (package name [goto-definition](https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition)) worked like charm for me. Please try once. You can download directly from Atom.

**This package is DEPRECATED. Please check it in Github.**

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Thanks. 
The default key binding is CTRL+ALT+ENTER

Comment: This is the only package which works on a little bigger project. Thanks! I have tried atom-ctags, symbol-get, goto packages and none of them worked :-(. Either caused atom crash or took too long.

Comment: This is pretty sluggish but it works. My project is tiny so I don't really think this will scale well.

Comment: Not working good in javascript ES6 (P.S. I'm developing with React), and can't go to definition inside node modules files...just uninstalled it.

Comment: How to follow symbol which are outside the project ?

Comment: What's the alternative to this deprecated package?

Comment: autocomplete-python

Comment: please see the answer by Q-Bart below: 
 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34227075/12377933

Comment: @StevenShaw, python-tools works absolutely fine for python [tested on atom 1.45.0, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, python3]. Install using this command `apm install python-tools`. after installing restart your atom editor and it will work (eg. ctrl+alt+g).

Comment: As of May 2022, python-tools stills works with CTRL+ALT+G

Answer (score 35):

<s>I believe the problem with "go to" packages is that they would work diferently for each language.</s>

If you use Javascript [js-hyperclick](https://atom.io/packages/js-hyperclick) and [hyperclick](https://atom.io/packages/hyperclick) (since [code-links](https://atom.io/packages/code-links) is deprecated) may do what you need.

---

Use [`symbols-view` package](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view) which let your search and jump to functions declaration but just of current opened file. Unfortunately, I don't know of any other language's equivalent.

There is also another package which could be useful for go-to in Python: [python-tools](https://atom.io/packages/python-tools)

As of May 2016, recent version of Atom now support "Go-To" **natively**. At the [GitHub](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view) repo for this module you get a list of the following keys:

- `symbols-view:toggle-file-symbols` to *Show all symbols in current file*
- `symbols-view:toggle-project-symbols` to *Show all symbols in the project*
- `symbols-view:go-to-declaration` to *Jump to the symbol under the cursor*
- `symbols-view:return-from-declaration` to *Return from the jump*

[image: screenshot]

I now only have one thing missing with Atom for this: mouse click bindings. There's an open [issue on Github](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2256) if anyone want to follow that feature.

Comment: Thanks @corpy code-links looks like a neat idea for js and I'll try it out. I've had to adjust to a workflow that doesn't include this feature since I mostly code in php.

Comment: I wouldn't know about php packages. And this may be a long shot, but have you tried [symbols-tree-view](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-tree-view)? It's certainly not what you wanted, but at least it'd give some easier visual navigation if your php classes/files are long

Comment: Much appreciated. I will take look and see what it has to offer.

Comment: Can you find rails (.erb) files symbols?

Comment: python-tools works absolutely fine for python [tested]. Install using this command `apm install python-tools`. after installing restart your atom editor and it will work (eg. ctrl+alt+g).

Answer (score 19):

I also had the same problem. And I find the solution:

```
CTRL+ALT+G
```

Update:

Thanks to @Joost, install Atom package [python-tools](https://atom.io/packages/python-tools) to make it work

Comment: As of Jul 11, 2016 this command does not seem to do anything.

Comment: This combination launch the Styleguide of Atom, that will show you all the UI components used in Atom. It is useful as a reference when developing themes and packages.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+g run the Styleguide, Ctrl+Alt+g does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Just for you wondering where this comes from, `CTRL+ALT+G` is the default key binding for `goto:definition` in the `python-tools` atom package.

Comment: You also need to have python installed on your machine for `python-tools` to work

Comment: Useless package. Only work for inline file, can't jump to other file if the function is imported

Answer (score 13):

The functionality is already present in atom via the [Symbols View package](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-view) you don't need to install anything.

The command you are searching for is **symbols-view:go-to-declaration** (Jump to the symbol under the cursor) which is bound by default to **cmd-alt-down** on macOS and **ctrl-alt-down** on Linux.

just note that it will work only if you will have generated tags for your project, either via [this package](https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) or via ctags ([exuberant](http://ctags.sourceforge.net) or not)

Comment: By default on Linux you will get Emacs ctag. As [said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968545/4970442) to run the _real_ `ctags` install `exuberant-ctags` package (considering [this](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/issues/171) and [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/struggling-with-ctags/12550/6) seems the one Atom currently use).

Comment: "**ctrl-alt-down** on Linux" -- Great choice of keys, it's not like that is used to move around workspaces. Damn atom, why so complicated. :-\

Comment: @Daniel - or if you're unfortunate to have just the right kind of *windows*, you might **flip your screen** instead! damn windows, why so stupid ;/

Answer (score 7):

This feature has been built-in into Atom editor (see: [`symbols-view` package](https://atom.io/packages/symbols-view)), but you need to generate ctags symbols file for your project <sup>[GH-9](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/issues/9), [GH-20](https://github.com/atom/symbols-view/issues/20)</sup>.

To do that, install `ctags` command (e.g. `brew install ctags` on macOS), then:

1. Append, link or copy `ctags-config` to your `~/.ctags`, example on macOS:

   ```
   ln -vs "$(find /Applications/Atom.app -name ctags-config -print -quit)" ~/.ctags
   ```
2. Go to your project folder and run:

   ```
   cd your/project/directory
   ctags -R .
   ```
3. Restart Atom editor.

---

Alternatively you can use [`symbol-gen` package](https://atom.io/packages/symbol-gen) to generate ctags symbols file for your project based on the options found in [`.ctags`](https://github.com/weskinner/symbol-gen/blob/master/lib/.ctags) file. You can install it from *Atom Package Manager* by: `apm install symbol-gen`. Then hit <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to generate tags file for your project.

---

After following above, you can use *Go To Declaration* option from the context menu.

On macOS you can use also use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> to jump to a function/method in the current ,editor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> to go to declaration.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, you'll need to install only 2 packages. Follow the steps below.

1. Open atom, go to **Packages**(top bar) --> **Settings View** --> **Install Packages/Themes**.
2. Type "goto" in the search field and click the packages button on the right.
3. Install both **"goto(1.8.3)"** and **"goto-definition(1.1.9)"**, or later versions. Make sure both of them are enabled after download.
4. If necessary, you can restart atom (for some people).
5. It should be able to work now. Right-Click on the method/attr/whatever, then select **"Goto Definition"**

Answer (score 2):

Check out **goto package**:

> This is a replacement for Atom’s built-in symbols-view package that
>   uses Atom’s own syntax files to identify symbols rather than ctags.
>   The ctags project is very useful but it is never going to keep up with
>   all of the new Atom syntaxes that will be created as Atom grows.
>
> Commands:
>
> - cmd-r - Goto File Symbol
> - cmd-shift-r - Goto Project Symbol
> - cmd-alt-down - Goto Declaration
> - Rebuild Index
> - Invalidate Index

Link here: https://atom.io/packages/goto (or search "goto" in package installer)

Answer (score 2):

For Typescript users, the "atom-typescript" package adds a typescript aware symbols view, you can trigger it with Cmd+R, and it works great to jump to methods-

https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript#alternative-to-symbols-view

Answer (score 1):

Use [atom-ctags](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ctags) as a package for C language with all things you need:

- Generated ctags for your project. Auto-complete.
- Go to declaration: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click by default.
- There are customizable options for Click action.

Comment: Can't we return to declaration using Alt + Right Click?

Comment: You can return, but to return you should go to somewhere first of all. After you do "Alt + Click", you can return with "Alt + Left Click" of course. And then "Alt + Right Click" to "re-return" forward.

Comment: If you try this package and then remove it remember to also re-enable symbols-view: `apm enable symbols-view`.

Answer (score 0):

As of November 2018 the package [autocomplete-python](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-python) offers this functionality with this key combo:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

with mouse cursor on the function call.