# Atom editor: list and jump to definition(s) in project

Tags: atom-editor, symbols, goto, exuberant-ctags, go-to-definition

As already mentioned I'm using the Atom text editor.
I'm currently working on a project written in c++. Of course it is desirable to jump to the definition of a function (in another project file), or other uses of this function (within the project). As far as I know this can be achieved with the packages I'll mention below. I want the package to display me the definition along with the path to the corresponding file which holds the definition and ideally the line where it occurs.

I'll welcome any comments and suggestions on how to solve the below mentioned problem(s) I have with (one of) the packages. Moreover I'm also thankful about pointers to possible solutions or posts concerning my problem(s), or how I can achieve this with another package.

Here is what I found / tried / did so far.

## `goto`

Currently I'm using this package, although it is rather slow and does not show the arguments of the function as e.g. `atom-ctags` does, but it's the only package which displays me the files I need to see.
It shows me where the function is defined as well as where it is also used. However it does not show me the path to the file corresponding file it refers to.

## `atom-ctags`

I also tried this package, building the tags is quite fast and moreover it show me the path to the file. But this package only lists the `.cc` files and not the `.h` files. It appears to me as if it only shows me the other uses but not the definition, which is obviously a problem.
I also tried generating the ctags myself and changing the command options in the settings of the package, unfortunately without any success.

## Atoms built-in `symbols-view`

In order to get this to work, one needs to generate the symbols. This can be, for example, achieved with the `symbol-gen` package. However, it shows me some of the definitions, but also no `.h` files. Moreover, jumping to the definition results in a `Selected file does not exist.`, therefore it is not usable at all.

## `goto-definition`

Just for completeness, there is also this package. It does not work for me, since c++ is not supported but maybe others will find it useful.

## `symbols-plus`

Again, for completeness, this should be a replacement for the atom built-in, but when disabling the build-in it does not show me any jump functionality nor is a short cut mentioned.

Comment: there is also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077396/how-can-i-jump-to-class-method-definition-in-atom-text-editor-do-i-need-to-ins?rq=1 , which also deals with jumping to definitions

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, nothing really works well. I have tried Symbol Tree View but it but barely works.