# How can i jump to class or method defination with JavaScript in Atom?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I use Javascript `js-hyperclick` and `hyperclick` , and i do not know how to control that find the defination .

I looking for some answer [How can I jump to class/method definition in Atom text editor? (Do I need to install a package?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077396/how-can-i-jump-to-class-method-definition-in-atom-text-editor-do-i-need-to-ins), can't find the solution.

Is any one can teach me instruction , it would be appreciated.

My environment is Mac.

Comment: So the answer you linked doesn't work in your case, as in when you right-click a function, the option isn't there?

Comment: I found that i hold the command button , i can jump to class or method now , thanks for your responding